# SparkContext not initializing in zeppelin

Tags: pyspark, apache-zeppelin

While I am trying to import SparkContext from pyspark on apache zeppelin, following error is shown:
[image]

Comment: Please post errors as text, otherwise search & google will not find them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the spark.pyspark interpreter instead of the python one if you need a spark context.
Try:

```
%spark.pyspark
print(sc)
```